# How to list Unit tests with errors in sonarqube

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube

We have a jenkins server, with which we create our build, execute the Unit Tests and check the code coverage.
It then publish the results in SonarQube.

Currently in SonarQube, I see that I've 18 Unit Tests errors(and 20 Unit tests failures). I'm wanting to solve this issue now, but I'm unable to reproduce them in local, so it's probably connectivity issues, but i cannot be sure.

If I go to the Unit tests errors, I get such screen, but I'm unable to see which one is failing. We have more than 7000 units tests, so it would be nice to be able to see only the one that are failing.
[image]

Does somebody knows how to get this list of failed unit tests?

Comment: Why not rely on jenkins for this ? what's the point of running a SonarQube analysis if you have failing unit tests ?

Comment: Well, from our point of view, sonarQube was more to check the quality of our code(otherwise, why publishing unit tests results to it). and jenkins was only to trigger the differents builds. Also we have a dashboard with the sonarqube indicator.